# What options are there to 'normalize' values from a heavy-tailed distribution?

Tags: r, normalization, splines, interpolation, heavy-tailed

We have some data collected acquired from a complex setup, that is expected to come from a "fairly normal" underlying distribution. However when I investigate the data it appears that it's fairly heavy tailed compared to normal distribution, for all replicates.

[image]

Here the density plots of different replicates are given, the dashed red line corresponds to normal dist with the same mean and stdev as the data.

One possible explanation we came up with is that the technical setup amplifies the extremes, likely due to the approximation and subtraction of background noise and similar signal processing steps that are out of our control.

Is it possible to normalize the data to compensate for the heavy tails? Since the data points are already logarithmized values, I don't think taking the log is an option.

An idea that came up was to do a spline interpolation based on QQ plot

[image]

Is this a good strategy? Any tips otherwise?

Comment: What's excess kurtosis of the data?

Comment: Excess kurtosis is kurtosis measured on a scale on which the Gaussian or normal has value 0. It is sometimes called just kurtosis. (I think @Aksakal knows that; he wants the number for these data.)

Comment: Some transformations that pull in the tails symmetrically are cube root; neglog := sign(y) log(1 + |y|); and asinh.

Comment: @Aksakal approx 17.9

Comment: these are very fat tails indeed. Look at Lambert transformation here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.2265.pdf

Comment: Why do you need this to be normal?

Comment: @Glen_b for subsequent analysis, essentially. Many of the workflows commonly used in biomedical research have normality assumptions for this type of data.

Comment: Neither "subsequent analysis" nor a "workflow" should inherently carry assumptions. Procedures (tests, confidence intervals) have assumptions (to which some are sensitive and others less so). The reason I ask is that frequently -- perhaps the majority of the time -- people askign about transformation are (often vainly) trying to achieve normality of a variable that there's not even a normality assumption about (i.e. they're completely wasting their time -- and ours) trying to get normality for something they don't actually need it for. ...ctd

Comment: ctd... I often see it in the case of regression, for example, where there's no assumption of normality in relation to either IVs or marginal DVs (yet those are the things people try to use transformations to normality on). Even when normality is required for some procedure, rather than transformation to normality, very frequently it's better to simply choose a better model for the data  and use different procedures for tests and or confidence intervals.

Comment: +1 on Glen_b comment.  If you are still interested for transforming and (!) a better model take a look at Lambert W x F distributions.  Almost certainly `LambertW::Gaussianize()` will solve your problem . See https://github.com/gmgeorg/LambertW for details.